# How to solve "waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath" in the code?

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

My Program has failed to locate the `pass-code` field which is in the next page of login page, so I have tried to locate it by a wait as follows (piece of code shows).

I have already tried by increasing the wait time to 100, but it also not working.

It shows as program stops in the password field even without reaching to the `sing-in` button.

An error received as :

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //input[@id='user-passcode'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:81)

It always shows as it fails in 81 wherever the code...

```
WebElement unfield = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user-name']"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(unfield).click();     
unfield.clear();
unfield.sendKeys("test");      
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user-password']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user-password']")).sendKeys("test");
WebElement test = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='SIGN IN'])[1]/following::button[1]"));
Actions actions_signinclick = new Actions(driver);
signinclick_buttonclick .moveToElement(test).click();
//this will display in next page
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='user-passcode']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user-passcode']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user-passcode']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user-passcode']")).sendKeys("1234");      
WebDriverWait submit_button = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
submit_button.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@_ngcontent-wks-c3=''][text()='SUBMIT']/self::BUTTON")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@_ngcontent-wks-c3=''][text()='SUBMIT']/self::BUTTON")).click();
```

Please help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: Your locator : `By.xpath: //input[@id='user-passcode']` not found, please share url link to solved the issue.

Comment: Hi there,I cannot be able to share the url as it is owned to my company.

Comment: or please share html code

Comment: <input _ngcontent-ekv-c3="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" formcontrolname="accessCode" id="user-passcode" placeholder="Passcode" required="" type="text">

Comment: it this code enough?

Comment: please more, all element in login form

Comment: Hi there,I cant added the full code here,only 99 character allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

Change this line :

```
signinclick_buttonclick .moveToElement(test).click();
```

To be :

```
signinclick_buttonclick.moveToElement(test).click().build().perform();
```

Then change the locator `//input[@id='user-passcode']` to be `//*[@id='user-passcode']` like this :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='user-passcode']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='user-passcode']")).click();
```

Comment: Hi there,thanku so much,It is redirecting to the next page and successfully locate the field.But again it shows as unable to locate the element for submit button in that page.Why this is happening?Is  there any reason to happen this again and again?

Comment: Sadly i don't know the html `submit` button your mean,  so i don't know you wrong or true with locator you choice, but i think your issue related with locator strategy. With share html code (better if available url link), it will give many information, because each web page developed with different way. Example with `click` event, there are several type in selenium, and each web page have different behaviour.

Comment: Thanku Frian,Ill find a way.Your answer helps me a lot,Thanks again